# Yii2 Framework Relation with Sum Not Working Correctly

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am having an issue when trying to sum related data from another table.

I have created a getter as follows...

```
public function getContItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ContItems::className(), ['CONTNO' => 'inspQuoteNo'])->sum('LINETOT');
}
```

When i use this i get the following error: "*frontend\models\Quotes has no relation named "contItems".*"

When I declare the getter as follows i get no error but dont want to loop through the results for the sum as its very slow to do this:

```
public function getContItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ContItems::className(), ['CONTNO' => 'inspQuoteNo']);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why the sum is not working and coming as if there is no relation declared with the sum?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a relation should return an object `\yii\db\ActiveQuery`. If you append `->sum(...)` to the query it will return an integer.

But you can use the query returned by the relation like follows:

> $sum = $quote->getContItems()->sum('LINETOT');